# MongoDB find() with dot notation does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am creating a search function in my app that searches through: title, description and product manufacturers name. So far, searching with title or description **works** fine but it does not work when I try manufacturers name (in fact, it is the only one that uses dot notation in querying)

I have some data in DB:

```
title: 'GLT 488',
description: 'an item',
Manufacturer:
    { _id: 5ababaa8d1c9c006c8fd8975,
    key: 'audio-note',
    name: 'Audio Note',
    },
```

This is how I am using MongoDB's find function:

```
const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
q.find({
    $or: [
        {'title': regex},
        {'description': regex},
        {'Manufacturer.name': regex}
    ]
},
```

Comment: And the query is? Simply `'audio'` works fine for me. I see `_id` in the sub-key there. Using mongoose perhaps? Maybe your schema is incorrect and it interferes with the issued query. So what is the schema? On in fact is `Manufacturer` actually sitting in another collection and you use `.populate()`. Because that's what it looks like.

Comment: Yes I am using mongoose as it is part of KeystoneJS, is schema a db model? I do use populate, and Manufacturer comes from relationship type.

Comment: I am also using ```populate('ProductType Manufacturer')``` but it might be wrong

Comment: Yeah, you need to look at the answers on the duplicate question as shown in the large box above your question. You want to match on a regex to something that is actually in a different collection. There are different ways to do that to the simple query you tried, and that is what the existing answers explain.

Comment: I have looked at example and did like it's told, but it is still not working
```q.find({Manufacturer: regex})
            .populate('Manufacturer', 'name')
            .exec(function(err, results) {
                if(err) {
                    next(err);
                } else {
                    locals.data.products.results = results;
                    next(err);
                }
            })
```

Comment: Look harder. Look specifically for the one that does not even use `populate()` at all, but uses `$lookup` and tells you exactly what the problems with using `populate()` for this type of query are. Even the correct answers that do use `populate()` show a usage here that you still are not using. In fact all of them show different usage.